# Accessing Objects After 'x' in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I have an array `allLayers` where I am trying to access all objects that follow the clicked `a`. How do I select every object that follows the clicked `a`?

```
allLayers = []
for i in [0...30]
    card = new Layer
    allLayers.push(card)     

for a in allLayers  
    a.on Events.Click, ->
        ## how do I get every object that follows "a" in the array??
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: It's worth noting that using for loops with potentially a sync actions is a bit dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

```
allLayers = new Layer for [0..30]
allLayers.map (a,i) ->
    a.on Events.Click, ->
        remaining = allLayers[i+1..]
```

It's worth noting that using for loops with potentially a sync actions is a bit dangerous.

```
setTimeout((-> console.log(i)), 1000) for i in [1..10]
```

And

```
[1..10].map (i) -> setTimeout((-> console.log(i)), 1000)
```

Don't do quite the same thing due to the way scope works in JavaScript; only functions introduce scope.